# Is there a way to push changes with a GitHub action?

Tags: github, github-actions

This question refers to this: https://github.com/features/actions

I have written a GitHub action to build my code and create a production bundle. I'd like to have that included into my repository by committing the changes to origin/master. This seems like an obvious feature for GitHub actions to have but I can't find it anywhere. How do I commit changes with a GitHub action and push them?

Comment: First of all, they're not duplicates. Mine discusses how to commit and push, not just push. Secondly, mine predates that question by about 4 months.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

**Update:** Please see the following question/answer for full details about how to push changes back to the remote.
[Push to origin from GitHub action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57921401/push-to-origin-from-github-action/58393457#58393457)

An alternative option is [create-pull-request](https://github.com/peter-evans/create-pull-request) action. It will automatically commit changes to a new branch and raise a pull request for you to review the changes. I wrote a detailed explanation about it as an answer to another question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58004257/11934042

Answer (score 27):

I found the [stefanzweifel/git-auto-commit-action](https://github.com/stefanzweifel/git-auto-commit-action) to be the best solution. It's really as easy as:

```yaml
- uses: stefanzweifel/git-auto-commit-action@v4
```

One could, of course, tune the parameters, like commit message, file globs and many others.

Comment: Note that this doesn't work for repos owned by an organization: `Error: .github#L1
stefanzweifel/git-auto-commit-action@v5 is not allowed to be used in <your organization> /<your repository>. Actions in this workflow must be: within a repository owned by <your organization> or created by GitHub.`

Comment: Blame your organization, not this action. The error clearly says what's the problem. https://docs.github.com/en/organizations/managing-organization-settings/disabling-or-limiting-github-actions-for-your-organization

Comment: Hi madhead, I didn't say anything about blame? This is useful information for others. Best regards,

Comment: You said precisely "this doesn't work for repos owned by an organization". But it's not "this" that does not work, it's your organization security settings. It has nothing to do with this particular action. Any other action outside or you org or `actions` repos would not work for you. That's completely off-topic for the question asked.

Comment: I disagree. It doesn't matter whose fault it is. Users are coming here for a solution to this question and many will run into the same issue. Best regards,

Comment: And they have plenty of working solutions here, but what you're talking about is a completely different issue.

Comment: That's just repeating your point of view and not addressing my point. Let's agree to disagree.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is to just integrate this action: https://github.com/cds-snc/github-actions/tree/master/auto-commit

It's a little frustrating because it has a default name/email that's ridiculous so you have to fork it to fix it but it otherwise works well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use git auto commit actions `stefanzweifel/git-auto-commit-action@v5`
(more information: [github.com/stefanzweifel/git-auto-commit-action](https://github.com/stefanzweifel/git-auto-commit-action))
**Note**: You will need to allow write `contents: write` permissions.

**Example:**

```yaml
name: Format

on: push

jobs:
  format-code:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    permissions:
      # Give the default GITHUB_TOKEN write permission to commit and push the
      # added or changed files to the repository.
      contents: write

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      # Other steps that change files in the repository

      # Commit all changed files back to the repository
      - uses: stefanzweifel/git-auto-commit-action@v5
```