# Unable to commit and push back changes made by github action (invalid user)

Tags: git, github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I have following step at the end of my action workflow. It runs when code is pushed to master, the idea is to commit all files changed by github action back to master once this action finishes.

```
    - name: Commit and push changes
      run: |
        git config --global user.name 'myGithubUserName'
        git config --global user.email 'myEmail@gmail.com'
        git add -A
        git commit -m "Increased build number [skip ci]"
        git push -u origin HEAD
```

However I keep getting following error, even though I am configuring user and email.

> fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': Device not
>   configured
>
> ### [error]Process completed with exit code 128.

Note, this runs on `macOS-latest` and uses git that comes prepackaged with it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**actions/checkout@v2**

Version 2 of checkout resolves the detached HEAD state issue and simplifies pushing to origin.

```
name: Push commit
on: push
jobs:
  report:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Create report file
        run: date +%s > report.txt
      - name: Commit report
        run: |
          git config --global user.name 'Your Name'
          git config --global user.email 'your-username@users.noreply.github.com'
          git commit -am "Automated report"
          git push
```

If you need the push event to trigger other workflows, use a `repo` scoped [Personal Access Token](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line).

```
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.PAT }}
```

**actions/checkout@v1 (original answer)**

The problem is that the `actions/checkout@v1` action leaves the git repository in a detached HEAD state. See this issue about it for more detailed information: https://github.com/actions/checkout/issues/6

The workaround I have used successfully is to setup the remote as follows:

```
git remote set-url origin https://x-access-token:${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}@github.com/username/repository
```

You may also need to checkout. You can extract the branch name from the `GITHUB_REF`:

```
git checkout "${GITHUB_REF:11}"
```

Here is a complete example to demonstrate.

```
name: Push commit example
on: push
jobs:
  report:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: Create report file
        run: date +%s > report.txt
      - name: Commit report
        run: |
          git config --global user.name 'Your Name'
          git config --global user.email 'your-username@users.noreply.github.com'
          git remote set-url origin https://x-access-token:${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}@github.com/$GITHUB_REPOSITORY
          git checkout "${GITHUB_REF:11}"
          git commit -am "Automated report"
          git push
```

By the way, I have written a GitHub action which may help you achieve what you want to do. It will take any changes made locally during a workflow, commit them to a new branch and raise a pull request.
https://github.com/peter-evans/create-pull-request

Also see this related question and answer. [Push to origin from GitHub action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57921401/push-to-origin-from-github-action/58393457#58393457)

Comment: Hmm, I added this line before my `git add -A` step, changed `/username/repository` to reflect my repo, but am still getting an error, although now a different one `remote: Invalid username or password. fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/MyOrg/MyRepo/'`. Thank you for linking your action, I will have a look through it.

Comment: I updated the post to use the secret directly, not from an environment variable. Does that help?

Comment: For anyone who likes to use as little bytes as possible, `x-access-token:` part can be ignored; `https://${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}@github.com/username/repository` will work just fine.

Comment: @Samira I don't think that's true in all cases. I needed to clone a private repo within a github action, and it failed without the `x-access-token:` part.

Comment: @con-- Hah. Didn't use remote url editing for some time, but it shouldn't (sic!) be needed anymore as you can run `actions/checkout` with `token` argument nowadays.

While waiting for [v2](https://github.com/actions/checkout/pull/70) i'm using `actions/checkout@e8bd1dffb6451bb0d84dbcd3ed059daca1371180` with `token` argument and it pushes just fine without touching any remote settings... at least on public repo (don't have any private which needs autocommits to confirm it works with them).

Comment: @Samira I just use that version fro Checkout and was able to achieve the commit and push, thanks, but Idk why I cant use v2 as written by peterevans, Also I'm working on pull_request

Comment: @Samira: Please share the code for token (I can simply pass following), am I right here?

      with:
        github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

Comment: @amandeep1991 [Here](https://github.com/rotators/Fo1in2/blob/fdf01b00b87320702e9e8055c5f6f26e1e1073d8/.github/workflows/schedule.yml#L93-L98), ignore `if`/`fetch-depth`. I'm using PAT there but it'll work just fine with `GITHUB_TOKEN`.

Comment: @Samira: Thanks I got the fully working code now ( I wanted to update the version in my bundle which gets uploaded to pypi.org). Same is below as one of the answers.