# Tagging, and building and uploading a python library

Tags: github-actions

I have a github action that runs when a branch is merged into master. It should tag the repo with a version number that it obtains from setup.py, and then push the tag. It should then build the package and upload it to a package repository.

Progress so far: Building and uploading works, tagging does not

```
name: Deploy Library



on [push]



jobs:

  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu latest

    steps:

    - uses: actions/checkout@master

    - name: Set up Python env

       uses: actions/setup-python@v1

         with:

           python-version: '3.6'

    - name: Install Deps

    run: |

      python -m pip install --upgrade pip

      pip install wheel

      pip install twine

    - name: Build

       run: |

         python setup.py build bdist_wheel

    - name: Tag

       env:

         GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

        run: |

          VERSION=*sed magic on setup.py*

          git tag v$VERSION

          git push origin v$VERSION
```

Everything works except for the git push at the end. The logs complain about the need for a username and password (I only have the GITHUB_TOKEN), and anyway, actions/checkout didn't complain...

I've checked the github actions page, and I can't find one relating to tagging.

Comment: I posted the full steps for making the local git repository completely usable, but in your case you might only need to set the remote with the `GITHUB_TOKEN`

Answer (score 0):

The `actions/checkout@v1` action leaves the git repository in a detached HEAD state. So in order to push back to the repository there are a few steps required.

Set git config for the user you want to be the commit author:

```
git config --global user.name 'My User'
git config --global user.email 'myuser@example.com'
```

Set the remote:

```
git remote set-url origin https://x-access-token:${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}@github.com/username/repository
```

You may also need to checkout. You can extract the branch name from the `GITHUB_REF`:

```
git checkout "${GITHUB_REF:11}"
```

Related questions and answers:

- [Push to origin from GitHub action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57921401/push-to-origin-from-github-action/58393457#58393457)
- [Unable to commit and push back changes made by github action (invalid user)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58257140/unable-to-commit-and-push-back-changes-made-by-github-action-invalid-user/58257219#58257219)