# github action for updating package.json

Tags: github, github-actions

is there any github actions for updating the packages version is package.json [the packages own version , not dependency] ?
Ideally for push action , it should update the version and check in the changes back to repo

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any actions that handle this complete flow. However, if you are able to update the version in a `run` script command it's fairly straightforward to commit back to the repository yourself in a workflow. See the following answer for how to prepare the checked out repository and git config in order to push to the remote.

[Push to origin from GitHub action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57921401/push-to-origin-from-github-action/58393457#58393457)

Alternatively, you might find [create-pull-request](https://github.com/peter-evans/create-pull-request) action useful for this use case. It will commit changes to the Actions workspace to a new branch and raise a pull request. So if you call `create-pull-request` action after `npm version` during a workflow, you can have that change raised as a PR for you to review and merge.

For example:

```
on: push
name: Update Version
jobs:
  createPullRequest:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: Bump version
        run: npm version patch
      - name: Create Pull Request
        uses: peter-evans/create-pull-request@v1
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          commit-message: Bump version
          title: Bump version
```

Note: Using `on: push` may not be the best trigger for this use case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.But I am looking to update my own version on commits ;not dependency versions...almost like just run a npm version command and commit back to repo

Comment: I misunderstood what you wanted to do. Updated the answer.

Comment: You will need to set a username/email with the following:  

git config --local user.email "some@email.com". 
git config --local user.name "GitHub Action".

Comment: If you need to increment the old version of one, you could use this action to retrieve the current one https://github.com/marketplace/actions/ga-project-version

Comment: So if I use `on: push` to update package version and then push to origin, it re-triggers the workflow again, which does a new push and again the workflow. Sort of an endless loop. Any idea how to resolve this. @peterevans

Comment: @SubhamSaha 
you can use something like this
add a keword in the commit


`git commit -m "some commit message [ci-skip]"`


and then check in your GA action file if it includes that in the commit messsage
`if: "!contains(toJSON(github.event.commits.*.message), '[ci-skip]')"`

(or do this https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/skipping-workflow-runs)

Comment: Yes @pgarzina I finally was able to do so. So I was updating the package version as part of the ci job with the help of standard-version library. And it required to make a push, which was triggering the github bot to restart the workflow with a self formed commit message (`chore(release):version`), thus didnot have the opportunity to add any specific string like the one you mentioned. But later put the check against that string.