# Automate semver incremention in package.json by github actions based on labels

Tags: github, github-actions, package.json, semantic-versioning

This question is very close to [this 3 year old question from 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58311847/github-action-for-updating-package-json).

I'm seeking advise/reference to a bot/github action that semver bumps up the package.json version (as a commit) on merge/rebase pending on the labels `major`, `minor` or `patch` that the PR has.

Answer (score 2):

You can test out [`Konsentus/action.bump-version-and-tag`](https://github.com/Konsentus/action.bump-version-and-tag):

> This action will find the last version tag made on the current branch, bump it and tag the current commit with the new version.
>
> **If a package.json file is present, the version contained will also be bumped to the same version as the tag**.
>
> As tags are commit specific and not branch specific, these version tags are prefixed with the current branch name, e.g. master/v1.0.0.

Example

```yaml
name: Bump Version and Tag
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - 'master'
      - 'sit'
      - 'alpha'
      - 'sandbox'
jobs:
  bump-and-tag:
    env:
      GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
    name: Bump and Tag
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

      - name: Get Tags
        run: git fetch origin +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*

      - name: Bump Version
        id: bump_and_tag
        uses: konsentus/action.bump-version-and-tag@v2
```