# How to save build files (React) using Github Actions

Tags: reactjs, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, github-actions

I am trying to build react code using github actions.
But after successfully building the files i want to save it in a particular location say "build" folder in the repo.
I am currently able to build the files but not save them in the repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to try and commit your build artifacts back to the repository yourself in a workflow see the following answer for how to prepare the repository and git config.

[Push to origin from GitHub action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57921401/push-to-origin-from-github-action/58393457#58393457)

Alternatively, you might find [create-pull-request](https://github.com/peter-evans/create-pull-request) action useful for this use case. It will commit changes to the Actions workspace to a new branch and raise a pull request. So if you call `create-pull-request` action after creating your artifacts during a workflow, you can have that change raised as a PR for you to review and merge.

For example:

```
on: release
name: Update Version
jobs:
  createPullRequest:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      ...
      (your build steps)
      ...
      - name: Create Pull Request
        uses: peter-evans/create-pull-request@v2
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          commit-message: Add build artifact
          title: Add build artifact
```

Comment: Thanks that link helped. now building in github branch create-react-app Build files directly in github.

Comment: The answer seems not to answer the exact question asked! @Adithyad please share how you able to build directly in github.

Answer (score 0):

I just used https://github.com/s0/git-publish-subdir-action and it worked great. It just dumps files from a given folder into a branch. Here's an example workflow file that worked for me:

```
name: Build Data

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Set up Python 3.x
      uses: actions/setup-python@v2
      with:
        python-version: '3.x' 

    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install -r tools/requirements.txt

    - name: Run python script
      run: python tools/data_builder.py

    # THIS IS WHERE THE DATA IS PUBLISHED TO A BRANCH
    - name: Deploy
      uses: s0/git-publish-subdir-action@master
      env:
        REPO: self
        BRANCH: data_build
        FOLDER: tools/data_build
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

And here is in action: https://github.com/2020PB/police-brutality/blob/4818ae367f2627c7a456bd3c6aa866054e618ac8/.github/workflows/build_data_ci.yml

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.

Comment: Thank you for calling that out @double-beep I've added the workflow file to clarify.