# Trigger GitHub actions if push in another repo

Tags: github, github-actions

In one of my repos (repo A), there is a script that gets the content of a file on another repo (repo B, not one of mine). Therefore, I would like to trigger a GitHub action on repo A each time there's a push on repo B. I didn't see this case [on GitHub actions trigger documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows), is this possible?

Comment: No, GitHub actions doesn't support that natively. The closest you could get is a [cron trigger](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onschedule), then check it anything has changed.

Comment: Okay so run my GitHub action on repo A every day for example?

Comment: Yes, exactly like that.

Comment: Okay, thanks, put this as answer if you want

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trigger a GitHub Action when another repository creates a new release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58465057/trigger-a-github-action-when-another-repository-creates-a-new-release)

Answer (score 5):

You can execute each day a script with cron in order to start or not your workflow. A script can read easily the date of last commit of another repository.

**Detect when the last commit is less than a day old**

With this script, the exit code is 0, only if the last commit is less than a day old.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
exit $(curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/wikimedia/mediawiki/commits/REL1_36 | jq -r "((now - (.commit.author.date | fromdateiso8601) )  / (60*60*24)  | trunc)")
```

***Execute the script with cron each day***

```
name: trigger

on:
  schedule:
    - cron:  '30 5 * * *'

  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  check:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - run: ./isUpdated.sh
```

***Start your workflow when a new commit exists since yesterday***

```
name: Your workflow
on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: ["trigger"]
    types: [completed]

  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  check:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.conclusion == 'success' }}
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - run: echo ok
```

Answer (score 4):

edit: this won't work since OP doesn't have push access to repo B

I think that you might be able to get what you want by using the `repository_dispatch` [event](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#repository_dispatch). This essentially triggers the workflow when an endpoint is pinged with the correct payload.

From the documentation:

> To trigger the custom `repository_dispatch` webhook event, you must send a `POST` request to a GitHub API endpoint and provide an `event_type` name to describe the activity type. To trigger a workflow run, you must also configure your workflow to use the `repository_dispatch` event.

My best guess is that your desired solution can be achieved by creating 2 workflows: 1 in Repo A that runs `on: repository_dispatch`, and 1 in Repo B that runs `on: push` and contains a step that hits Repo A's API (e.g. using `curl`). This would give you the following events:

1. You push to Repo B.
2. Repo B's `on: push` workflow is triggered, and the step that hits Repo A's API endpoint (e.g. using `curl`) is run.
3. Repo A's API endpoint receives the payload and the `on: repository_dispatch` workflow is triggered.

Comment: Thanks but repo B is not mine so I can't push to it