# How would I go about building TS code via GitHub actions?

Tags: node.js, typescript, github-actions

Firstly, I just wanted to mention that I don't have much experience in using GitHub actions. However, I would like my typescript code to be built, and pushed to a production branch whenever there is a commit to my main branch. Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: [Google is your friend here.](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/typescript-compiler)

Comment: Personally I would not want to have a secondary commit for every commit I do just get my typescript files built. Why commit your javascript files at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following two actions to achieve what you want.

1. Build your code with the following action: [typescript-compiler](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/typescript-compiler)
2. Then follow this question to push the resultant build to Github [Push to Github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57921401/push-to-origin-from-github-action/58393457#58393457)

Basically, you are done, if you need any extra step you can always go to [actions marketpalce](https://github.com/marketplace?type=actions) or build your own.