# Workflow failed git commit and pushing

Tags: git, github-actions

I created a model for price prediction and I want to auto update it at a scheduled time daily using GitHub Actions.

That is the code for the workflow:

```yaml
name: Update_Model

on:
  schedule:
    - cron: "13 16 * * *"

jobs:
  update_model:
    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
      - name: Check Out Code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
    
      - name: Set up Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v4
        with:
          python-version: '3.9'

      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: |
          pip install -r requirements.txt
          pip install yfinance  # Add this line to install yfinance

      - name: Update Model
        run: |
          git config user.email "jdominion123@gmail.com"
          git config user.name "DOMINION-JOHN1"
          python update_model.py

      - name: Commit and Push
        run: |
          git add .
          git commit -m "Update LSTM Model"
          git push origin HEAD:refs/heads/main
        env:
          GOLD_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GOLD_TOKEN }}
```

The model is successfully retrained but it fails to push changes to update the model and it's bringing this error message:

```
Run git add .
[main b79c5d4] Update LSTM Model
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
remote: Permission to DOMINION-JOHN1/LSTM-Gold-Price-Prediction.git denied to github-actions[bot].
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/DOMINION-JOHN1/LSTM-Gold-Price-Prediction/': The requested URL returned error: 403
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Push to origin from GitHub action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57921401/push-to-origin-from-github-action) Make sure to add `permissions: contents: write` as done in the accepted answer.