# Building a static website with Jinja and GitHub actions - unable to deploy website even though it looks like the webpages are being created?

Tags: github, gitlab, github-actions, gitlab-ci, github-pages

I'm trying to migrate a static website template from GitLab Pages to GitHub Pages. The template uses Python/Jinja to generate static webpages which then get built with GitHub Actions. While migrating to GitHub, the scripts run without an error but the generated `index.html` file doesn't actually seem to exist anywhere. What's going on?

[Here](https://gitlab.com/aalok-sathe/simple-personal-website) is the website template that I'm using. There are two main files of concern - The GitLab CI file that is called to execute the script:

```yaml
image: python:3.6-alpine

pages:
  stage: deploy
  before_script:
  - python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
  script:
  - cd public/
  - python render.py
  - cd ..
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public/
```

This is how I migrated it to ensure it works with GitHub actions:

```yaml
name: Build and Deploy

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest  # use the latest version of ubuntu

    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v3 #v3 to ensure that everything is run on node16

    - name: Set up Python
      uses: actions/setup-python@v3 #v3, node12 will be deprecated soon
      with:
        python-version: 3.9  #just upgrading from the alpine 3.6 version

    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install -r requirements.txt #install the requirements

    - name: Build and Deploy
      run: |
        cd public/
        python render.py
        cd ..

    - name: Upload artifacts
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
      with:
        name: public
        path: public/
```

and the `render.py` file in the `public` directory:

```py
import json
import yaml
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader, DebugUndefined
from jinja2_markdown import MarkdownExtension
from pathlib import Path
import datetime
from glob import glob  # Add this line for importing glob
from tqdm import tqdm

# Create an empty dictionary to store template variables to be passed
data = dict()

# Add today's date, properly formatted, to the data dict to display at the bottom
# of the page
data['today'] = datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

# Load assets that can be used by templates. Assets are yaml files with data
for pathname in tqdm(glob('assets/*.y*ml'), desc='Loading assets'):
    path = Path(pathname)
    fname = path.stem
    with path.open('r') as f:
        assetdata = yaml.safe_load(f)
    if type(assetdata) is not dict:
        assetdata = {fname: assetdata}
    data.update(assetdata)

# Scan sections in the sections directory; there will be a section header for
# each one of these
data['sections'] = []
sectionfiles = glob('sections/*.html')
try:
    order = yaml.safe_load(Path('sections/order.yaml').open('r'))
    comparator = lambda key: (order + [Path(key).stem]).index(Path(key).stem)
except FileNotFoundError:
    comparator = lambda key: key
for sectionfile in tqdm(sorted(sectionfiles, key=comparator), 
                        desc='Processing sections'):
    sectionfile = Path(sectionfile)
    fname = sectionfile.stem
    sectionenv = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('sections'), 
                             extensions=['jinja2_markdown.MarkdownExtension'],
                             undefined=DebugUndefined)
    sectiontempl = sectionenv.get_template(sectionfile.name)
    data['sections'] += [dict(name=fname, content=sectiontempl.render(**data))]

# Create a Jinja2 environment instance
jinja_env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('templates'), 
                        extensions=['jinja2_markdown.MarkdownExtension'],
                        undefined=DebugUndefined)
# Get template
template = jinja_env.get_template('landing.html')

# Render template and output it to index.html, the default page to show
output_path = Path('output')  #change path as needed
output_path.mkdir(exist_ok=True)

output_file_path = output_path.joinpath('index.html')
with output_file_path.open('w') as out:
    out.write(template.render(**data))

print(f"index.html saved at: {output_file_path}")
```

I added a line explicitly stating *where* `index.html` gets saved (`output/index.html`) but **no such repository/file combo actually gets created in the GitHub repository**. As far as I can tell, read/write permissions are enabled for GitHub Actions (I ensured that this setting was enabled for the repository) but no index.html file still gets created.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Where are you expecting the files to be at the end of this process? Assuming `render.py` has produced the `<public>/output/index.html`, you should have the `output/index.html` file inside the artifact zip that's attached to the job. **"no such repository/file combo actually gets created in the GitHub repository"** -- correct. You aren't committing or pushing anything, just uploading the zip. Would you rather commit and push and build your pages from a directory in a branch, or upload the zip and deploy the zip?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I specifically needed information about how to add files created with GitHub actions to the repository, so I can do that now. I suspect GitLab does something different but I'm not sure. I'll update this question with the answer when I solve the problem.

Comment: If all you want is to commit and push then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57921401/push-to-origin-from-github-action/58393457#58393457) would be better than some random untested unofficial action.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
- uses: stefanzweifel/git-auto-commit-action@v5
```

to the end of your GitHub Actions `.yaml` file.

Something like

```
- name: Push artifacts back to the original repository
      uses: stefanzweifel/git-auto-commit-action@v5
```

works. The code relies on [this](https://github.com/stefanzweifel/git-auto-commit-action) repository.